# PGFPlots: Thick line goes outside drawn y-range

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

What is the best way to avoid thick lines in PGFPlots from going outside the drawn y-range? For example, near the maximum in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle, no markers]
\addplot +[domain=0:3, ultra thick] {5+10*x-5*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there something better than setting y limits by hand? Sometimes (especially when using `restrict y to domain`) I like to let PGFPlots pick sensible limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `enlargelimits=upper` in the axis options, as in

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle, no markers, enlargelimits=upper]
\addplot +[domain=0:3, ultra thick] {5+10*x-5*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `clip=false` to the axis options. This may be useful if changing the `enlargelimits` setting gives unwanted results.

Comment: So that I can learn, can someone explain why this answer has been voted down or voted to delete as this approach has worked for me based on advice from here (I think). Is there an unintended consequence? I can then edit or delete my answer.